# Magento 2 code validation Unescaped output detected warning

Tags: magento2, validation

I've created a Magento2 Module, When I validate the PHP code, am getting the  **Unescaped output detected**.

I got the following solutions from that blog **/* @noEscape */** moreover, it's not fixing the problem.

I want to know how to fix this issue, and need some detailed technical explanation of the /* @noEscape */

Comment: please check and update me https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/310915/magento-2-code-validation-unescaped-output-detected-warning/310923#310923

Comment: Magento coding standard not allow to use echo  that's why there are different way to use this.

Answer (score 6):

**You  can solve using This**

> For HTML Attribute

```
<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($var) ?>

or

<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr("Demo text") ?>
```

> **For URL**

```
<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getUrl('*/*/forgotpasswordpost')) ?>
```

> For used insted of **echo**

```
<?= $block->escapeHtml('Name') ?>

<?= $block->escapeHtml($var) ?>

<?= /* @noEscape */ $var ?>
```

**Note: Some time code is required then we not change in code so use this line**

```
//@codingStandardsIgnoreStart

Your code 

//@codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
```

**This is perform coding standard ignore this line**

***I Hope This Hepls You.***

Answer (score 2):

You use it in your templates like this

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/9544fb243d5848a497d4ea7b88e08609376ac39e/app/code/Magento/ConfigurableProduct/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/product/edit/super/wizard.phtml#L14-L16

```
<div class="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getData('config/dataScope') ?>" data-role="step-wizard-dialog" data-bind="scope: '<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getForm() ?>.<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getModal() ?>'">
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

You can use phpcs markers too

https://gist.github.com/DominicWatts/3a36f94bef8ef572d7b25237c3cd969e

Comment: is it advisable to skip escaping the form key ? or will it impact differently if we escape it